# How to access names of the element within lapply function in a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

I want to generate a boxplot for all the variable in my data frame. But the problem is i cannot get the x axis to be labelled with the variable name which is looping via lapply. Any thoughts.

```
df=data.frame(a=rnorm(100), b=rnorm(100), c=rnorm(100), d=rep(1:2,50)) # data
df$d=as.factor(df$d)
```

Function for box plot

```
Boxplotfun=function(x,i){
  if(is.numeric(x)) {
    p <- ggplot(df, aes(d, x, group=d)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "red", fill = c("gold","darkgreen")) + coord_flip() + theme_light() + ggtitle(paste(names(x)))
    plot(p)
  } 
}

l=lapply(df[-ncol(df)], Boxplotfun)
```

Comment: I used to use `mapply` for this type of problem. Something like `mapply(myfun, x = df, title = names(df))` an make sure myfun takes a title argument. Now I would use `tidyr::gather` to make df into a two column df (variable, value) and then use `facet_wrap(~variable)`

Comment: @RichardTelford: This is not working. I have added param for ttitle in the myfun too but it is still showing me x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make Richard's comment into an answer:

```
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100), b=rnorm(100), c=rnorm(100), d=rep(1:2,50)) # data
df$d <- as.factor(df$d)

df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, 'var', 'val', -d)
ggplot(df2, aes(d, val, fill = d)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "red") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gold","darkgreen")) +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_light() +
  facet_grid(var~.)
```

[image]

Comment: This is not feasible if the variables are not comparable on same scale thanks for the solution. could you give a solution using mapply?

Comment: Use `facet_grid(var~., scales = 'free')`.

Comment: @Thanks Its Perfect.

Comment: when i do this for variable with different range all together like 1-100, 10000-10100 and even higher. Using free scale i only get a range of 1-100 on my x axis. Isnt this should be like distributed on the max scale between all the variables i take. I hope you get the point.

Comment: Yeah ok, that's a bug in `ggplot2` caused by combining facets with `coord_flip`. [See also here.](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1470) You can use `geom_boxploth` from the [`ggstance`](https://github.com/lionel-/ggstance) package to circumvent this.

Comment: It needs higher version of R, will give it a try later on.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the dataframe as first argument to lapply, you can use the names of the dataframe directly and just refer to your dataframe inside of your plot function.

Instead of using aes, I have also used aes_string so that I can pass "x" inside and ggplot understands that I am not looking for variable x but rather for the variable whose name "x" refers to

```
Boxplotfun=function(x) {
  if(is.numeric(df[, x])) {
    p <- ggplot(df, aes_string("d", x, group="d")) + 
      geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "red", fill = c("gold","darkgreen")) + 
      coord_flip() + theme_light() + 
      ggtitle(x)
    plot(p)
  } 
}

ll <- lapply(names(df[-ncol(df)]), Boxplotfun)
```

**Edit:**
If you want the legend to appear, you should, as Axeman's answer has shown, specify fill inside your aes and use scale_fill_manual to pick the colors:

```
Boxplotfun=function(x) {
  if(is.numeric(df[, x])) {
    p <- ggplot(df, aes_string("d", x, fill="d")) + 
      geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "red")+
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("gold","darkgreen")) +
      coord_flip() + theme_light() + 
      ggtitle(x)
    plot(p)
  } 
}
```

Comment: @ Thanks Choubi i will try this out